# Changing default collation of a SQL Server 2008 instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, collation

When I try to change the default collation of a SQL Server instance using this commandline:

```
setup.exe /QUIET /ACTION=REBUILDDATABASE /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SAPWD=********* /SQLCOLLECTION=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

I get the following message:

Microsoft (R) SQL Server 2008 Setup 10.00.1600.22
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The following error occurred:

> The setting 'SQLCOLLECTION' specified is not recognized.
>
> Error result: -2068578301 Result facility code: 1204 Result error
>   code: 3
>
> Please review the summary.txt log for further details

Is there anything I'm missing ? Do I need to do something special for the setup.exe to find the `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLCOLLATION=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

SQLCOLLATION not SQLCOLLECTION